# Problems with loading existing SQFlite Database in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am trying to open a existing SQLite Database in my Flutter app but i always get that Error message in the Console when starting the App:

```
I/OpenGLRenderer(16880): Davey! duration=949ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=32058088200606, Vsync=32058088200606, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=32058101631102, AnimationStart=32058101709175, PerformTraversalsStart=32058101714227, DrawStart=32059029835685, SyncQueued=32059030411883, SyncStart=32059030862195, IssueDrawCommandsStart=32059030915893, SwapBuffers=32059035930789, FrameCompleted=32059037678966, DequeueBufferDuration=3920000, QueueBufferDuration=1405000, 
E/SQLiteLog(16880): (1) no such table: Links
E/SQLiteLog(16880): (1) no such table: Links
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MemberProfileDealer 17 1 1
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MessageDealer 45 0 1
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor LiveInfoDealer 497 1 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor ProductInfoDealer 810 0 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MarkInfoDealer 1511 0 3
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MemberProfileDealer 4 0 1
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MessageDealer 41 0 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor ProductInfoDealer 823 0 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor LiveInfoDealer 1095 0 2
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MarkInfoDealer 1404 0 5
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MemberProfileDealer 19 0 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MessageDealer 46 0 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor LiveInfoDealer 491 0 1
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor ProductInfoDealer 805 0 0
I/flutter (17672): sdlu conver_refactor MarkInfoDealer 1410 0 2
```

This is my Database_Helper Class:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

import 'model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'DSA_Database.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await rootBundle.load(join('assets', 'DSA_Database.db'));
  }

  Future<List<Titles>> getTitles() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var titles = await db.query('Links');
    List<Titles> titlesList =
        titles.isNotEmpty
            ? titles.map((e) => Titles.fromMap(e)).toList()
            : [];
    return titlesList;
  }
}
```

The Database is already added in the pubspec.yaml file

```
assets:
    - assets/DSA_Database.db
```

I am pretty new to SQLite so i don't 100% know if i am doing it right.

And Yes, i double checked the naming of the Table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

in the `_onCreate` you should create the table if not existed
like this code

```
 Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await rootBundle.load(join('assets', 'DSA_Database.db'));
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Links(id id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , <your Title class Properties>)");
  }
```

and when you try to get the data instead of `var titles = await db.query('Links');`

do this `var titles = await db.query('SELECT * FROM Links');`

i hope this work for you ,
you also have to check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Comment: With this Solution, i got a new Error - but it's the only Error now.
```E/SQLiteLog(15193): (1) near "SELECT": syntax error``` 
And with that Error still no Data in my app

Comment: ok use `var titles = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Links');` instead of `var titles = await db.query('SELECT * FROM Links');`

Comment: Thank you again for the help!
But now again, there is this first Error: ```E/SQLiteLog(30029): (1) no such table: Links```